# AFrame shape disappearing right before left side of screen

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, webvr

I'm trying to make a VR app with AFrame and there is a bug where objects will disappear right before they reach the left side of the screen, Its really distracting. Does anyone know how to fix this? I know it is happening because the program is no longer displaying the objects out of the field of view to save processing power, so maybe the answer is to increase the margin around the edge where it still displays them. I know this isn't because of any of my code because it happens on any AFrame program. Also, it only seems to happen on the right eye.

Comment: What version of A_Frame?

Comment: according to my script tag, it is version 0.8.0.  <script src="https: //aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>